# QtQuick 2.0 GL error

Tags: qml, qt5

I'am currently on my first QtQuick 2.0 project, but everytime I build my project, I get the following error:

```
cannot find -lGL
```

That's all. I think it is the *libglib* library that is missing, but I could not figure out which package I have to install to solve this problem. The QtCreator runs on my Desktop with Debian Wheezy 64bit. I do not the error when building on my Laptop running LMDE 32bit.

**EDIT:** Finally I could collect some more information:

```
16:57:09: Starting "/usr/bin/make" 
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64 -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64/lib -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/Qt5.1.0/5.1.0/gcc_64/lib -o Test main.o edgebutton.o edgetype.o qtquick2applicationviewer.o moc_qtquick2applicationviewer.o moc_edgebutton.o moc_edgetype.o   -L/opt/Qt5.1.0//5.1.0/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Quick -lQt5Declarative -lQt5Qml -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Network -lQt5Script -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Bananarang] Error 1
16:57:09: The process "/usr/bin/make" terminated with return value 2.
Error while building/deploying of project Test(Kit: Desktop Qt 5.1.0 GCC 64bit)
During execution of step 'Make'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not libglib. It's libGL. It's usually provided by mesa or by your GPU's vendor. Find which package provides libGL.so and install that one. Under Debian it should be called `libgl1-mesa-dev`.

Comment: Since I am using the nvidia 304 driver I have to install libgl1-nvidia-blubb right?

Comment: Yes -- but don't install that package manually, follow your distribution guides about how to install the properietary nvidia drivers. That will also install the right libGL version.

Comment: Also it's very likely that the NVIDIA's blob won't ship OpenGL headers, so you still need them from mesa-dev.

Comment: Installing *libgl1-mesa-dev* fixed it. Thanks!